# How to set Encoding UTF8 in the Powershell script that have HTML tag to show persian characters in HTML page?

Tags: html, powershell, encoding, utf-8

I'm a beginner of powershell. I want to create a web page with powershell and I put HTML tags inside powershell script like below:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

'<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl/master/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">
    <title>جستجو</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>فهرست همه کاربران</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>نام</th>
            <th>نام خانوادگی</th>
            <th>نام کاربری</th>
            <th>واحد سازمانی</th>
            <th>دپارتمان</th>
            <th>عنوان شغلی</th>
            <th>آدرس ایمیل</th>
            <th>شماره تلفن</th>
            <th>وضعیت اکانت</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>firstName</td>
            <td>lastName</td>
            <td>userName</td>
            <td>OU</td>
            <td>Department</td>
            <td>jobTitle</td>
            <td>emailAd</td>
            <td>phonNo</td>
            <td>Enabled</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>'
```

I put the HTML tags inside ' ' in powershell script (.ps1 file). It shows everything correct but I want to find a way to set the encoding to UTF8 to show multi language characters. Any help is appreciating.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to write whole HTML contents to a file with UTF-8 encoding, right?

Pass the whole string to `Out-File -Encoding utf8` command via pipeline.

```powershell
'<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">
 ...
</html>' | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -Path index.html
```